# Is there a way to get collection name used in template data context?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Is there a way to get collection name used in template data context like this one:

```
Template.someTemplate.events({
  'click': function () {
    var self = this;
    if (dataContextUsedInThisTemplate() === 'CollectionA') {
      CollectionA.update(self._id, {modifier}, callback);
    } else{
      CollectionB.update(self._id, {modifier}, callback);
    };
  }
});
```

thank You so much....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is something built-in.
Somewhere in your code, you will have to set data context so just store some value to know which collection are you using.
Or you can do something like this:

```
 var a = CollectionA.findOne(self._id);
 var b = CollectionB.findOne(self._id);
 if(a)
   CollectionA.update(self._id, {modifier}, callback);
 else if(b)
   CollectionB.update(self._id, {modifier}, callback);
```